# Chartjs display bug when pushing data to graph

Tags: javascript, electron, chart.js

My friend and I have a problem with chartjs. We created an app to track your financial status. We wanted to push data to the graph, but after the third entry, the graph only displays two data points, eventhough three points are created pushed to the graph. Here are screenshots and the code. Can you help us? Thanks.

[Chartjs displays only the datapoint before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yl1Qa.png)

[Console shows 400](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qsbhr.png)

```js
var config = {
 type: 'line',
 data: {
  labels: [],
  datasets: [{
   label: $('#idDropdownKonto option')['0'].innerText,
   backgroundColor: 'rgb(0, 87, 255)',
   borderColor: 'rgb(0, 87, 255)',
   data: [],
   fill: false
  }, {
   label: $('#idDropdownKonto option')['1'].innerText,
   fill: false,
   backgroundColor: 'rgb(0, 255, 133)',
   borderColor: 'rgb(0, 255, 133)',
   data: []
  }]
 },
 options: {
  responsive: true,
  title: {
   display: true,
   text: 'Finanzr Chart'
  },
  tooltips: {
   mode: 'index',
   intersect: true
  },
  hover: {
   mode: 'nearest',
   intersect: true
  },
  scales: {
   xAxes: [{
    display: true,
    scaleLabel: {
     display: true,
     labelString: 'Datum'
    }
   }],
   yAxes: [{
    display: true,
    scaleLabel: {
     display: true,
     labelString: 'Kontostand'
    }
   }]
  }
 }
};
window.onload = function() {
 var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
 window.myLine = new Chart(ctx, config);
 console.log("------Store--------");
 console.log(store.get('dataSchema'));
 console.log("--------------");
 if(myLine.data.datasets[0].data.length == 0) {
  console.log("STORE DATA");
  window.myLine.data.datasets[0].data.push(store.get('dataSchema'));
  window.myLine.update();
 }
};

function addDataGraph() {
 let Betrag = $('#inputBetrag').val();
 let Konto = $('#inputKonto').val();
 let Beschreibung = $('#inputBeschreibung').val();
 var betragArray = [Betrag];
 var kontoArray = [Konto];
 var beschreibungArray = [Beschreibung];
 var dataPointArray = beschreibungArray.concat(kontoArray);
 var sortDateArray = [aktuellesDatum].sort(dateFns.compareAsc);
 var dateArray = [sortDateArray];
 var ArrayLength0;
 var ArrayLength1;
 if(myLine.data.datasets[0].data.length == 0) {
  console.log("Dataset not found");
  myLine.data.datasets[0].data.push(Betrag);
  store.set('dataSchema', Betrag);
 } else {
  console.log("--------------");
  console.log(store.get('dataSchema'));
  console.log("--------------");
  //=> 50
  console.log("Dataset found");
  if(Konto === 'Postbank') {
   console.log('Postbank');
   var BetragBerechnen = JSON.parse(store.get('dataSchema')) + JSON.parse(Betrag);
   console.log(BetragBerechnen);
   myLine.data.datasets[0].data.push(BetragBerechnen);
   // myLine.data.datasets[0].label = 'Postbank';
   myLine.data.labels.push(dateArray);
   store.set('dataSchema', BetragBerechnen);
  }
 }
 myLine.update();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.8.0/dist/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="150"></canvas>

<button type="button" class="bg-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-700 text-white rounded-full py-2 px-4 m-2" onclick="addDataGraph()" name="button">Update Graph</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

app.compontent.html

```
<canvas id="line-chart" style="width: 100%; height:250px;"></canvas>
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Chart } from 'chart.js';
  chart: any = '';
  ngOnInit() {
 this.chart = new Chart('line-chart', {
      type: 'line',
      data: {
        labels: ["JAN 05", "JAN 06", "JAN 07", "JAN 08", "JAN 10", "JAN 12", "JAN 15", "JAN 20", "JAN 21", "JAN 22", "JAN 23", "JAN 24"],
        datasets: [
          {
            data: [10, 12, 15, 12, 18, 12, 10, 12, 17, 12, 12, 20],
            label: "Africa",
            borderColor: "#3e95cd",
            fill: false
          }
        ]
      },
      options: {
        scales: {
          yAxes: [{
            display: false //this will remove all the x-axis grid lines
          }],
          xAxes: [{
            gridLines: {
              display: false
            }
          }]
        },
        legend: {
          display: false
        },
        tooltips: {
          callbacks: {
            label: function (tooltipItem) {
              console.log(tooltipItem)
              return tooltipItem.yLabel;
            }
          }

        }
      }
    });
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for replying to our question. A few questions though, we neither use typescript nor angular. As far as I can see you posted just the configuration and not how to push data. Can you please show us? Thanks